# Why wont the PowerBI Reports display on mobile?

Tags: powerbi, power-bi-report-server

we can see reports on PowerBI web within our company's network just fine, but when we try viewing on mobile in browser (not the app if there is one), we can get to the folders just fine, but the reports wont load, and says

> The webpage cannot be found HTTP 404

here is a simulation we tried on our computer by disabling the company proxy to simulate outside company network

the reports are for the most part static

we opened a ticket with MS, but so far not much help, so i am reaching out here for possible suggestions we might be missing

[image: simulation]

Comment: Try using their mobile app and it should be good, https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/mobile/

Comment: @Mboolean for the time being, thats not an option :/

Comment: The odd part is that you can get to the folders at all, not that the reports don't run.  Is your RS server normally accessible from outside your network?

Comment: @Eric Hauenstein nope, its restricted to only inside the company,  but recently we onboarded it to be accessed outside company as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

figured out the problem finally!

apparently the configuration team had the page redirect on mobile to a subfolder PowerBI

> https://analysis.domain.com/reports/powerbi

while it should have been navigating at the server level

> https://analysis.domain.com/reports/browse